# Why did my Nautilus stop displaying thumbnails for text files?

Tags: nautilus, thumbnails

I've chosen to have **plain-text files displayed with thumbnails** in Nautilus.
However, this has suddenly **stopped functioning the other day** (after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 I guess).

But there's **no such problem when I log in to a Guest session**, so **the problem is probably in user-specific settings, *BUT WHERE?***
(I emptied the thumbnail cache, but this made no difference.)

I wonder what else I can do in my **user settings/configuration to fix this** with so few options left in the Preferences menu :)

Comment: Did you change themes?

Comment: I changed both GTK and icon themes with no effect.

Comment: It seems to be working in my newly installed copy of Ubuntu 14.04. This may be something on your end with your settings. Try running a live USB session and see if it's the same?

Comment: @e.m.fields: Thanks, I've now made my question clearer with emphasis on **user-specific settings/configurations**.

Comment: I think I've finally found an answer to this question myself which can be seen here for reference: http://askubuntu.com/a/589903/47343